# How to cycle through channels of Mat image? (OpenCV) VS2010

Tags: opencv, cycle, channel

How can I cycle through array of Mat images? I want tried something like this but Visual Studio 2010 prints error 
error C2039: 'interator' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'

```
Mat bgr[3];
split (source,bgr);
for (std::vector<Mat>::interator it = split.begin(); it != split.end(); ++it )
imshow( "Channel", *it );
```

I believe OpenCV should have much simpler way, but I could not find it.

Comment: yourMat.at<type>(y,x) to get pixel at x/y coordinate. If pixel type is multichannel you can access the different channels from that pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, split is a function and I don't see in your code snippet that there is a vector called split.
If you want to iterate through an array, just do a simple for loop over your `Mat bgr[3]` array.

Second thing there is nothing called `interator` its called `iterator`, you misspelled the word.